# Typescript errors depending on order of types in a union type in react-select

Tags: typescript, react-select

I am using `react-select`([www.react-select.com](https://react-select.com)) with TypeScript and I am getting strange errors when using `options` prop. Consider this code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Select, {
  GroupedOptionsType,
  OptionsType
} from "react-select";

type OType =
  | GroupedOptionsType<{ label: string; value: string }>
  | OptionsType<{ label: string; value: string }>
  | undefined;

const options = [
  { label: "test1", value: "test1" },
  { label: "test2", value: "test2" }
] as OType;

const CustomSelect = () => {
  return <Select options={options} />;
};
```

Typescript is showing this:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<{ [x: string]: any; [x: number]: any; defaultInputValue?: string | undefined; defaultMenuIsOpen?: boolean | undefined; defaultValue?: ValueType<GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>>; ... 62 more ...; tabSelectsValue?: boolean | undefined; }>): StateManager<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'OType' is not assignable to type 'OptionsType<GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>> | GroupedOptionsType<GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>> | undefined'.
      Type 'OptionsType<{ label: string; value: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'OptionsType<GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>> | GroupedOptionsType<GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>> | undefined'.
        Type 'OptionsType<{ label: string; value: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'OptionsType<GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>>'.
          Property 'options' is missing in type '{ label: string; value: string; }' but required in type 'GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: { [x: string]: any; [x: number]: any; defaultInputValue?: string | undefined; defaultMenuIsOpen?: boolean | undefined; defaultValue?: ValueType<GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>>; ... 62 more ...; tabSelectsValue?: boolean | undefined; }, context?: any): StateManager<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'OType' is not assignable to type 'OptionsType<GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>> | GroupedOptionsType<GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>> | undefined'.
      Type 'OptionsType<{ label: string; value: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'OptionsType<GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>> | GroupedOptionsType<GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>> | undefined'.
        Type 'OptionsType<{ label: string; value: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'OptionsType<GroupType<{ label: string; value: string; }>>'.ts(2769)
```

But when I change the order of the types in the union type and put `OptionsType<>` first, it is totally ok.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Select, {
  GroupedOptionsType,
  OptionsType
} from "react-select";

type OType =
  | OptionsType<{ label: string; value: string }>
  | GroupedOptionsType<{ label: string; value: string }>
  | undefined;

const options = [
  { label: "test1", value: "test1" },
  { label: "test2", value: "test2" }
] as OType;

const CustomSelect = () => {
  return <Select options={options} />;
};
```

AFAIK order of types in a union type doesn't matter, but I suspect maybe it matters when using generics when type resolution happens, but I don't know. Strangely, I also did this (which is the same as above, but here I take `options` directly from the `SelectProps`), and it fails too:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Select, {
  Props as SelectProps,
} from "react-select";

type OType = Pick<SelectProps<{label: string; value: string}>, 'options'>

const options = [
  { label: "test1", value: "test1" },
  { label: "test2", value: "test2" }
] as OType;

const CustomSelect = () => {
  return <Select options={options} />;
};
```

Comment: @ford04 Tried it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you include the TypeScript version that you're using in your question? And all the different flags that you have enabled for compilation. And let's not forget, the compiler version...

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz or codepen (or any online editor)?

Answer (score 1):

I've modified react-select like this and it works in any way you want to, in any way. Test it.
I've also implemented Select All at once , when using multiple props set to true.

```
import clsx from 'clsx';
import React, { ComponentProps, FC, useState } from 'react';
import ReactSelect from 'react-select';

type Option = string | number;
type Options = { [key in Option]: any };

export interface SelectProps extends ComponentProps<typeof ReactSelect> {
  allowSelectAll?: boolean;
  allOption?: { value: string; label: string };
  options?: Options[];
  onChange?: (Options) => void;
}

const Select: FC<SelectProps> = function ({
  className,
  options,
  onChange,
  allowSelectAll,
  ...props
}) {

  const [allOption, setallOption] = useState({ value: "*", label: "Select All" });

  if (allowSelectAll) {
    return (
      <ReactSelect
        {...props}
        classNamePrefix="custom-select"
        className={clsx("custom-select", className)}
        options={[allOption, ...options]}
        onChange={selected => {
          if (
            selected !== null &&
            selected.length > 0 &&
            selected[selected.length - 1].value === allOption.value
          ) {
            setallOption({ value: "", label: "All Selected" });
            return onChange(options);
          }
          setallOption({ value: "", label: "Select All" });
          return onChange(selected);
        }}
      />

    );
  }

  return (
    <ReactSelect
      {...props}
      options={options}
      onChange={onChange}
      classNamePrefix="custom-select"
      className={clsx("custom-select", className)}
    />
  );


};

export default Select;
```